# VS2010 not show up if SQL Server 2012 installed before

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I installed them in this order:

1. Install SQL Server 2012 SP1 x64
2. Visual Studio 2010

This is the proper order that other developers recommended and as i did.
The problem is, if SQL Server 2012 installed on the system, VS2010 shortcuts are not show up.

How can I fix this?

**Note:** OS is Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug.

> A workaround is to navigate to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, right-click on the
>   shortcut called Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and select Pin to Start.
>   After this, there will be two shortcuts targeting devenv (one titled
>   Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools and one titled Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2010)

Refer: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730276/after-installing-sql-server-2012-on-my-windows-8-pc-visual-studio-2010-shortcuts-disappeared

Answer (score 3):

As the OP stated. I too installed SQL before VS. I always do. So I was baffled when i could not find my VS2010 shortcut.

It turns out that the icon is mis-named. If you open (or check the properties) of the icon in the Visual Studio 2010 start menu folder called "Sql Server Data Tools". You may find it is actually the VS 2010 IDE.

[image]

Workaround provided by 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730276/after-installing-sql-server-2012-on-my-windows-8-pc-visual-studio-2010-shortcuts-disappeared

Edit the shortcut start target. For instance. I made mine not display the splash page.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /nosplash
```

Then repin it to the start menu (right click).

Answer (score 1):

Installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 seems to fix this as well, its available to download from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691 If you run devenv.exe it should prompt you to do this also.